# how can i write an algorithm to multiply the total * quantity in a shopping cart using php $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

I am writing a shopping cart and have my data stored in the $_SESSION array, but would like to  calculate a total. below it the code I thought would work to do this, but it returns '1' in stead of a total!

> `$total = array($_SESSION['qty'],$_SESSION['pr']);`

/* I'll give you more code...thanks for your help!!
here is the code for my php cart:

```
<?php
```

> function item_list()
>     {
>       if(isset($_SESSION['qty'])){
>               $total = array($_SESSION['qty'],$_SESSION['pr']);

```
    foreach($_SESSION['qty'] as $key => $value)
    {?>
        <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['item'][$key]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['pr'][$key]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo array_product($total); ?>
    </tr><?php 
    }
}
```

> }
>
> session_start();
>
> if(isset($_POST['clear']) && ($_POST['clear'] == 'clear'))
>     {
>       session_destroy();
>       unset($_SESSION['qty']); 
>       unset($_SESSION['item']);
>       unset($_SESSION['pr']);
>       unset($_POST['qty']); 
>       unset($_POST['item']);
>       unset($_POST['pr']);
>     }
>
> if(!isset($_SESSION['qty']))  $_SESSION['qty'] = array();
>     if(!isset($_SESSION['item'])) $_SESSION['item'] = array();
>     if(!isset($_SESSION['pr']))   $_SESSION['pr'] = array();
>
> if(isset($_POST['qty']))
>     {

```
foreach($_POST['qty'] as $value)
{
    if(!$value == '') array_push($_SESSION['qty'], filter_var($value,
```

> FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
>       }
>       foreach($_POST['item'] as $key => $value)
>       {
>           if(!$_POST['qty'][$key] == '') array_push($_SESSION['item'], filter_var($value, 
>      FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
>       }
>       foreach($_POST['pr'] as $key => $value)
>       {
>           if(!$_POST['qty'][$key] == '') array_push($_SESSION['pr'], filter_var($value, 
>     FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
>       }
>     }
>
> ?>

Comment: Where are you actually multiplying?  Your $total variable is just an array of two $_SESSION variables.

Comment: `foreach($_SESSION['qty'] as $key => $value)` ??? what are you saving in $_SESSION['qty'], also you are using `$key` outside of the PHP scope, so it won't work, you should use `<?php echo $key?>` or `<?=$key?>`

Comment: An array is just a contiguous grouping of values.  There's no math (multiplication or otherwise) at work when you put things in an array.  How are `$_SESSION['qty']` and `$_SESSION['pr']` structured?

Comment: Upvote back to 0 because it's not a horrible question.  While the question contains code that shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how arrays work, isn't that exactly in Stack Overflow's wheelhouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a strange way to structure a shopping cart, but here's how to do it with that structure:

```
foreach($_SESSION['qty'] as $key => $value)
{
    $total = $_SESSION['qty'][$key] * $_SESSION['pr'][$key];
?>
    <tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['item'][$key]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $value; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['pr'][$key]; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $total; ?>
</tr><?php 
}
```

If you wanted to get a total of all quantity and cost of the cart:

```
function getTotals()
{
    $total = array('qty' => 0, 'price' => 0);

    foreach($_SESSION['qty'] as $key => $qty)
    {
        $total['qty'] += $qty;
        $total['price'] += ($_SESSION['pr'][$key] * $qty)
    }

    return $total;
}

$total = getTotals();

echo $total['qty']; // output the total quantity of items
echo $total['price']; // output the total cost for all items and quantity
```

I would recommend a better structure though, something like:

```
$_SESSION['cart']['items'] = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Screwdriver',
        'price' => 5,
        'qty' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Hammer',
        'price' => 10,
        'qty' => 1,
    )
);
```

Comment: I am still learning PHP at a fast rate, and you guys help me a ton!!!
@MrCode <<definitely a suitable name!!

Answer (score 0):

As per your cart array it is not able to hold multiple products you have to use multy dimensional array like this

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'] = array(
                array( "qty"=>5, "item"=>"tshirt", "pr"=>50.20), 
                array( "qty"=>2, "item"=>"Cell Phone", "pr"=>50.20),
                array( "qty"=>7, "item"=>"", "pr"=>50.20),      
               )
```

then you can write your code like this

```
function item_list()    
{

    foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $item_array)
    {?>
        <tr>
    <td align="center">Item:<?php echo $item_array['item']; ?></td>
    <td align="center">Qty: <?php echo $item_array['qty']; ?></td>
    <td align="center">Price :<?php echo $item_array['pr']; ?></td>
    <td align="center">Total : <?php echo $item_array['qty'] * $item_array['pr']; ?>
    </tr><?php 
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `$_SESSION['qty']` - that itself is an array.  A simple multiplication won't work.

Comment: here is my var_dump with no data entered in: array(3) { ["qty"]=> array(0) { } ["item"]=> array(0) { } ["pr"]=> array(0) { } }

Answer (score 0):

You should create yourself a `Card` class that is able to import/export data from the `$_SESSION` superglobal (or some other array if you mock it for tests, testing with `$_SESSION` can be akward) which is able to handle your data-structure easily and can calculate the total, too:

```
$cart = new Cart();
$cart->importFromArray($_SESSION);
// or:
$cart->importFromArray($_SESSION['cart']);

// later on:
$total = $cart->getTotal();

// somewhere else:
$cart->addItem(...);
...
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart->exportToArray();
```

That will allow you to more easily change the code over time.

Comment: Thank you. I'm brand new to Programming....I don't know why I keep getting down-voted. oh well....